# Open new html page instead current page(Ajax. JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have ajax request:

```
 function sendData(user) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/user-check',
            data: JSON.stringify(user),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/text',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success : function(completeHtmlPage) {
                alert("Success");
                var pageName = completeHtmlPage + ".html";
                window.open(pageName);

            },
            error: function() {

                alert('Error authorization');

            }
        });
    }
```

I want to open new page with name **completeHtmlPage + ".html"**.
How to open new page instead current page?

Comment: Do you mean in a new browser window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: Does it have to be in another window? Because if it's just a redirection you could use: `document.location.href = pageName;` rather than `window.open(pageName);`

Comment: It looks like your code should already do what you're saying you want it to do (assuming the AJAX request is returning a file name).  Is it not working as expected?

Comment: @ErikPhilips No, in current browser window

Comment: @Piyin  in the current browser window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do a redirection on the same page, you could change your `success` block to:

```
success : function(completeHtmlPage) {
    alert("Success");
    var pageName = completeHtmlPage + ".html";
    document.location.href = pageName;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes use 
location.href =  (relative/or absolute)